# Mule - Anypoint studio freezes on http response returning a pdf

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I'm new to Mule and Anypoint studio.

I'm integrating docusign in mulesoft. I'm having a weird issue.

One of the api of docusingn '/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}' will return a pdf doucment as the response.

However Mulesoft hangs and doesnt respond properly. The same command when run using curl command it works fine. Any help here pls

```
curl -i -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication: { "Username":"asdf@asdf.com.au", "Password": "asdf@123", "IntegratorKey":"a59asdfssadfdsc0af6237a37f"}' https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/c62afb10-455a-4f48-87cd-eb0f0949c9bd/envelopes/c8ed9a1d-dbb6-458f-b674-b8ecff9824b5/documents/combined > /data/t.pdf
```

Above command works fine. But not this one

```
 <flow name="docusignGet">
         <flow-ref name="docusignInit" doc:name="docusignInit"/>
         <flow-ref name="docusignCredentials" doc:name="docusignCredentials"/>
         <http:request config-ref="Docusign_HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
             <http:request-builder>
                 <http:uri-param paramName="accountId" value="#[sessionVars.docuSignAccountId]"/>
                 <http:uri-param paramName="envelopeId" value="7cadba0e-5fc6-4858-b0ea-c6eb13847a22"/>
                 <http:uri-param paramName="documentId" value="0"/>
             </http:request-builder>
         </http:request>
     </flow>
```

I added Object to Byte-Array transformer too. Same result.

[image]

Any help pls

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I found out the freeze issue. logging was root cause for the freeze.

So i disabled all the logs. now its not freezing, however the result is not obtained. Any help here ..

The HTTP response will be some thing like this (obtained from curl)

```
 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 < Cache-Control: no-cache
 < Content-Length: 175512
 < Content-Type: application/pdf
 < X-RateLimit-Reset: 1527051600
 < X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
 < X-RateLimit-Remaining: 1000
 < X-DocuSign-TraceToken: f0bfe1b3-674d-42f0-a410-1641e6f7cdc7
 < Content-Disposition: file; filename="Testing-_Please_sign_and_report.pdf"; documentid="combined"; filename*=UTF-8''Testing-_Please_sign_and_report.pdf
 < Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 04:04:54 GMT
 < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
 <
 { [16384 bytes data]
   9  171k    9 16384    0     0   8192      0  0:00:21  0:00:02  0:00:19  6097* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
 * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1360 length 103424
 * schannel: encrypted data got 46871
 * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 48231 length 103424
 * schannel: decrypted data length: 409
either its returning a file by parts. What i want is this HTTP connector to act as proxy and return the same payload back to the caller after streaming all the bytes. Let the caller then do what ever it wants (in my case its a Django server).
```

However i'm having an error.

```
No serializer found for class org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

I tried to add Object to ByteArray transformer after HTTP. But it didnt work .

I want the below command to work the way it works for docusign

```
 curl -i -v -X GET http://localhost:8081/api/docusign_get > tt.pdf
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

It turned out to be RAML issue. The RAML file what i had was having this

```
    /docusign_get:
  get:
    queryParameters: 
    responses: 
      200:
        body: 
          application/json:
```

where as the correct is

```
    /docusign_get:
  get:
    queryParameters: 
    responses: 
      200:
        body: 
          application/pdf:
```

didnt imagine that Mule is so dependent of RAML file

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTTP Request/Response is being generated correctly.

In your log4j2.xml file change, HttpMessageLogger to DEBUG level

```
<!-- Http Logger shows wire traffic on DEBUG -->
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger" level="DEBUG"/>
```

You should be able to see the request/response in the console output, compare it to the curl session, add -v to the curl command to get the request and response.

NB I prefer to use Fiddler for this, as amongst other things, it is better at handling binary data.

Comment: The initial issue was the logger. I had all debug logs, and it was freezing bcoz of HTTP Response. Now i'm having another error. Updating the question with the Update. Still unsure how to fix this. Thanks for the support

Comment: disabling all logs is the last thing I would do, change HttpMessageLogger to level WARN if the response is causing an issue, then use Fiddler to examine the traffic, you will need to set the http_connectors proxy to the Fiddler port usually localhost:8888

Comment: I have changed the log level to warn. If I use file and write to a local file all is well, however if I want to transmit this response as is to the caller then having an issue . Looks like the response is converted to some mule object . I have disabled parse also in http connector.

Comment: I will use Fidler and check if I get any information. Thanks once again

Comment: Just had that thought, as the file is comming in chunked binary, you need to read the stream for the http_connector to request the next chunk...which is exactly what your file connector is doing. So really all you need to do is pass the payload along, i.e. add another stream aware connector

Comment: latest HTTP connector has streaming option which is enabled. If I add File without streaming also works. The issue is HTTP connector is parsing the payload to 'org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream'. I did disable the Parse Response in HTTP. But still no help ```<http:request config-ref="Docusign_HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}" method="GET"   parseResponse="false" doc:name="HTTP" requestStreamingMode="ALWAYS">```

Comment: Mule uses streaming now, the main advantage is that you can handle large payloads without consuming huge amounts of RAM.  See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/streaming It can be a pain when developing because you cant read the stream without changing the current position.

Comment: Thanks for the support. You are very kind. Previously i was pointing to the same information. Issue is Mulesoft's HTTP resoponse will be BufferInputStream even if we turnoff Parse. And that can be transferred over the wire without converting. Nearest converter is File transformer, I dont want to use that as my usecase is just to act as proxy. I have a way out , to save to S3 bucket and forward the link . Lets see how i go

Comment: Got it working :) Hey ... It was my raml file issue. For this Get request my raml had response as application/json ... My bad. didnt check that .Thanks a ton